# Guessing game using Binary Search in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to guess a date in ten questions. I can get the code to ask only ten questions, but I am having trouble getting to the correct date. The program keeps going down to Decemeber 31 and I need it to guess the date the user is thinking. I am having trouble with the output. I am still very new to programming so any help would be great.

```
#Guess the Date
#Instructions for program
print ('Think of a specific date in any year')
print ('e.g., Jan 1 or Feb 29 or Jul 4 or Dec 25')
print ('Truthfully answer "Yes" or "No" to the following questions')
print ('I will determine the date in ten questions or less')

#Return a list of elements, each element is a date in a calendar year
def Calendar(monthNames, numDaysInMonth): #defining Calendar

    if len(monthNames) != len(numDaysInMonth): 
        return []

    dates = []
    idx = 0     #index is set to zero

    while idx < len(monthNames):
        for date in range(1, numDaysInMonth[idx] + 1):
            dates.append(monthNames[idx] + " " + str(date))
        idx = idx + 1
    return dates
monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]   #list of months
numDaysInMonth = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] #list of how many days in each month

#This is a binary search
first =Calendar(monthNames,numDaysInMonth) #first defined through the Calendar code block

def guess_game(first = Calendar(monthNames,numDaysInMonth)): #defining guess_game using months list and numDays item in the Calendar code to work the search

    if len(first) == 1:
        return first[0]

    mid = len(first)//2

    if is_earlier(first[mid]):    #list mindpoint
        return guess_game(first[:mid])
    else:
        return guess_game(first[mid:])

#Answer output, what is out putted in the python shell
def is_earlier(guess = 10): #defining is_ealier and setting the number of guesses equal to 10


    answer = input("Is {} earlier then your date? (Yes - earlier /No - not earlier) ".format(guess))#10 or less guesses to to find answer

    if answer.upper() == "Yes": #if true user can put No, no, n
        return True

    else:
        return False #if false user can put Yes, yes, y

guess_game() #intialize quess_game
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a stop condition

Comment: Thank you I was really having trouble with this that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with this line:

```
if answer.upper() == "Yes":
```

Even if the user inputs `Yes`, this is converted to `YES` by `str.upper`, so the `if` is never run.

Furthermore, what if the program manages to guess your date correctly? You do not give the user the option to choose that. You could change this by letting the user input 1, 2, or 3, for earlier, more, or equal.

Also, you've reversed the logic of your binary search. If the date is earlier than your guess, discard the latter half and vice versa.

---

```
monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]   #list of months
numDaysInMonth = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] #list of how many days in each month

#Return a list of elements, each element is a date in a calendar year
def Calendar(monthNames, numDaysInMonth): #defining Calendar
    if len(monthNames) != len(numDaysInMonth): 
        return []

    dates = []
    idx = 0     #index is set to zero

    while idx < len(monthNames):
        for date in range(1, numDaysInMonth[idx] + 1):
            dates.append(monthNames[idx] + " " + str(date))
        idx = idx + 1
    return dates

#This is a binary search
first = Calendar(monthNames,numDaysInMonth) #first defined through the Calendar code block

def guess_game(first = Calendar(monthNames,numDaysInMonth)): #defining guess_game using months list and numDays item in the Calendar code to work the search
    mid = len(first)//2

    val = is_earlier(first[mid])

    if val == 1:    #list mindpoint
        return guess_game(first[mid - 1:])
    elif val == 2:
        return guess_game(first[:mid + 1])
    else:
        return first[mid]

# Answer output, what is out putted in the python shell
def is_earlier(guess = 10): #defining is_ealier and setting the number of guesses equal to 10
    return int(input("{}: 1 - earlier, 2 - later, 3 - equal?: ".format(guess))) #10 or less guesses to to find answer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('Think of a specific date in any year')
    print ('e.g., Jan 1 or Feb 29 or Jul 4 or Dec 25')
    print ('Truthfully answer "Yes" or "No" to the following questions')
    print ('I will determine the date in ten questions or less')

    print(guess_game()) #intialize guess_game
```

Comment: @AnandSKumar Fixed.

Comment: You should return `first[mid]` , not `first[0]` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you the mid instead of the 0 helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One problem is with this part of your code:

```
if answer.upper() == "Yes": #if true user can put No, no, n
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`answer.upper()` would turn `'yes'` into `'YES'`, not `'Yes'`. The equality is never true, so every answer you give would be interpreted as a "no". The following would work:

```
if answer.upper() == "YES":
```

Another issue is with your logic for selecting which half of the search space to discard:

```
if is_earlier(first[mid]):    #list mindpoint
    return guess_game(first[:mid])
else:
    return guess_game(first[mid:])
```

If the midpoint is earlier than your date, you want to continue searching through the half that's later, not earlier.

Comment: @AnandSKumar: I'm sure there are more.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot!